# Why does a tungstenite WebSocket client only receive empty messages?

Tags: websocket, rust

I have a WebSocket client that queries a WebSocket server to stream data as it arrives:

```rust
use tungstenite::{connect, Message};
use url::Url;

fn main() {
    env_logger::init();

    let (mut socket, response) =
        connect(Url::parse("ws://public-node.test.dev:26657/websocket").unwrap())
            .expect("Can't connect");

    println!("Connected to the server");
    println!("Response HTTP code: {}", response.status());
    println!("Response contains the following headers:");
    for (ref header, _value) in response.headers() {
        println!("* {}", header);
    }

    socket
        .write_message(Message::Text("Hello, Test!".into()))
        .unwrap();
    loop {
        let msg = socket.read_message().expect("Error reading message");
        println!("Received: {}", msg);
    }
    // socket.close(None);
}
```

All I receive are empty `Received:`  messages:

```
test_ws git:master ❯ cargo run                                                 ✭
   Compiling anchor v0.1.0 (/Users/grokpronoia/rustTest/test_ws)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.22s
     Running `target/debug/test_ws`
Connected to the server
Response HTTP code: 101 Switching Protocols
Response contains the following headers:
* upgrade
* connection
* sec-websocket-accept
Received: {
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "error": {
    "code": -32700,
    "message": "Parse error. Invalid JSON",
    "data": "error unmarshaling request: invalid character 'H' looking for beginning of value"
  }
}
Received:
Received:
Received:
```

My goal is to query the server and return the current (and historical) data so that I can parse it accordingly. What am I missing, i.e., how can I return the data on the WebSocket server to my client?

I'm aware that `socket.write_message(Message::Text("Hello, Test!".into())).unwrap();` is superfluous.

Comment: *All I receive are empty Received: messages* — except for the message that indicates that there was an error — what happens when you **fix that error**?

Comment: That error is a result of tying to write a message with `socket.write_message()`. If I remove that then it just keeps repeating `Received: ` with no content every few seconds. I was expecting it to return data, not an empty message.

Comment: How do I stream any new messages from the WebSocket server to my client?

Comment: Your server expects a JSON, while your client just sends a string. Can you fix your server code? Or maybe post the serverside code here so we can help you?